# Why Am I unable to access object values that are available in my console in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completely shocked here. I can see the values right inside the console but I can't seem to access it on the webpage. If I try to display it, I will get an error instantly.
Here is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'profilePicture')
```

If I console.log like this in my react.js:

```
   {console.log(singleComment.author.profilePicture)}
```

I will see the image jpg links. See the attached file.
[image]

When I console.log like this:

```
console.log(singleComment.author)
```

I will see them like this:

[image]

You can see the objects there. I can access them all and display on the webpage, including

```
singleComment.author.username
singleComment.author.email
```

It is only

```
singleComment.author.profilePicture
```

that throws error if I want to display it on the webpage. What Am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to access to `singleComment.author.profilePicture` before `singleComment.author` exists?

Comment: when you print it with `console.log` inside React, you haven't got the object yet :)

Comment: It's possibly something else that's the issue, it's why it's really important to include a [mcve] inside your question's description.

Comment: How come I can access all other values under the same object?